# Mongo shell javascript array extensions

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, shell

So I am trying to use javascript array extensions (Array.prototype functions) in the mongodb shell and they don't seem to be defined. I think this is ok for me but I would very much like to use them in actual quires (namely group) and in map-reduce. I am using mognodb version 2.4.10. It says [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-javascript/) that 2.4 plus should have the ES5 array extensions. Are they just not available in shell?

Specifically the fill method does not work

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test.fill(0)
```

fails saying TypeError: Object 1,2,3 has no method 'fill'

Comment: Can you include an example using the [`Array.prototype` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) that don't appear to be defined? Does `mongo --version` definitely return 2.4.10?

Comment: Sorry about the wait. I can't use the fill method. mongo --version returns 2.4.10. Also I tried 2.4.6 on my laptop and it definitely works. On the other hand some of them do seem to work, concat, push, pop and many many others work however. I just tried fill first because it was first in the documentation. So for the most part I can use these all just fine.

Comment: [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) is part of ES6 (still experimental), so definitely not supported yet. Which documentation are you referring to? There are [nine new array methods](http://ie.microsoft.com/TestDrive/HTML5/ECMAScript5Array/Default.html) in ES5. For array extensions the MongoDB documentation links to the [ES 5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16), which does not include Array.fill().

Comment: well that solves that. I would except this as an answer btw. I'll edit my post to include that 'fill does not work' so others might find this in the future.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it was an issue with ES6 Array methods. I elaborated with some suggestions on extending JavaScript functionality as "not supported out of the box" isn't the full answer ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why isn't Array.fill() working?

`Array.fill()` is a proposed part of the ES6 spec (still experimental as at August, 2014), so is definitely not supported out-of-the-box in the MongoDB 2.4 or 2.6 `mongo` shell or server-side JavaScript.

#### What are the new ES5 array methods?

> 2.4 plus should have the ES5 array extensions

There are [nine new Array methods](http://ie.microsoft.com/TestDrive/HTML5/ECMAScript5Array/Default.html) in ES5: `indexOf`,
`lastIndexOf`, `every`, `some`, `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, and `reduceRight`.

You can find out more about available Array methods in the [ES5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.16).

#### Is there a workaround to use Array.fill()?

If you *really* want to use this function there happens to be a [reference implementation of `Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) in the Mozilla Developer Network documentation. You could embed this code in your Map-Reduce functions or store a [server-side JavaScript function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) in `system.js` as appropriate.

NOTE: In general, use of server-side JavaScript in MongoDB is discouraged for performance reasons. Server-side functions will add overhead to all server-side JavaScript contexts, so if you only need this for a specific or infrequently used Map-Reduce job you would probably be better embedding the code.

#### Extending the `mongo` shell

It is also possible to extend the `mongo` shell with custom JavaScript functions using one of several methods:

- Paste JavaScript code into an active `mongo` shell session.
- Use [`load()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/load/) to load and evaluate the contents of a JavaScript file.
- Save JavaScript code into [`~/.mongorc.js`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-mongorc-file) to have this loaded when you start the `mongo` shell.
- Use [`db.loadServerScripts()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) to load all JavaScript functions saved in the server-side `system.js` collection for the current database.